# Remove comment blocks in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm using the following bit of code to process a SQL Script and split it up using the GO command:

```
[string]$batchDelimiter = "[gG][oO]"

$scriptContent = Get-Content $sqlScript | Out-String
$batches = $scriptContent -split "\s*$batchDelimiter\s*\r?\n"
foreach($batch in $batches)
{
    if(![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($batch.Trim()))
    {
        $SqlCmd.CommandText = $batch
        $reader = $SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    }
}
```

The problem I have is when a GO command appears in the middle of a comment block:

```
/*
IF OBJECT_ID('AmyTempMapRetroDateFK') IS NOT NULL
DROP FUNCTION AmyTempMapRetroDateFK
GO
*/
```

Is there a way of removing all of the comment blocks before processing the script? I've seen a few examples in c# but nothing for Powershell.

Comment: Seems a bit dangerous, are you sure you'd want to remove all comment blocks?

Comment: I'd also need to remove all of the lines inside of the comment blocks. Its just to get round the problem where the split command is causing a syntax error when it splits on a GO inside a comment block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there are no *nested* comments (PSv3+ syntax):

```
(Get-Content -Raw $sqlScript) -split '(?s)/\*.*?\*/' -split '\r?\ngo\r?\n' -notmatch '^\s*$' |
  ForEach-Object { $SqlCmd.CommandText = $_.Trim(); $reader = $SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery() }
```

<sup>Note: If there's a chance that the final line doesn't end in a line break,
 use `'\r?\ngo(\r?\n|$)` instead of

`'\r?\ngo\r?\n'`</sup>

- `Get-Content -Raw`, available since PSv3, reads the entire file into a *single* string - it is the simpler and more efficient equivalent of `Get-Content $sqlScript | Out-String`
- `-split '(?s)/\*.*?\*/'` splits the input string by `/* ... */` spans; note the inline option, `(?s)`, which is required to make `.` match newlines too; non-greedy quantifier `.*?` is needed to only match up to the *next* `*/` instance; the result is an array of line blocks with the comment blocks excluded.
- `-split '\r?\ngo\r?\n'` then further splits that array by the word `go` preceded and followed by a newline.
  Note that `-split` is case-*insensitive* by default, so you needn't worry about case variations such as `GO`.
  (You could use alias `-isplit` to make the case-insensitive behavior more explicit; similarly,
  `-csplit` can be used for case-*sensitive* matching.)
- `-notmatch '^\s*$'` filters out blank / empty elements from the resulting array, and sends the filtered array through the pipeline (`|`).
- The `ForEach-Object` cmdlet then operates on each array element - now containing an individual SQL command - via automatic variable `$_`, which always represents the input object at hand.

Comment: This almost works but fails when the last line of the script is a GO command. I suspect its something to do with an end of file marker. Changing the Set-Content -Raw back to Get-Content | Out-String worked

Comment: @AndrewLackenby: I assume that stems from the file not ending in a newline; I've added a comment to the answer to show how to deal with that scenario. `Get-Content | Out-String` bypasses that problem, because it _always_ appends a trailing newline; however, `Get-Content -Raw` combined with the tweaked `-split` regex will perform better.

Answer (score 0):

A simplified version of the solution marked as the best answer, adapted here to remove PS comment blocks:

```
(get-content .\myscript.ps1 -raw) -replace "(?s)<#.+?#>",'' > myscript_Clean.ps1
```

Not sure why GO statements should interfere here. Applied to SQL comment blocks, this should do it:

```
(get-content .\myscript.sql -raw) -replace "(?s)/\*.+?*\/",'' > myscript_Clean.sql
```

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps you could split on `/*` and join the resulting array.
Then split that on `*/`, and join the resulting array.

Joins would be easier read with a `` `r`n ``(carriage return, newline) delimiter

Comment: Aside from there being no need for joining: in _regex_ contexts such as the RHS of `-split`, it's generally better to stick with regex syntax to avoid mixing "languages"; case in point: `'\r?\n'` is readily recognizable as a regex construct that matches a LF (`\n`), _optionally_ preceded by a CR (`\r?`); while `"\`r?\`n"` works too, its mix of PS escaping and regex syntax muddles the picture, and wouldn't work in a _single-quoted_ regex (which is to be preferred precisely to avoid the mixing of worlds).

Comment: On a meta note: It's fine to give solution _hints_ if you don't want to take the time to post a _solution_, but it's better to do that in the form of a _comment_, not an answer.
(You'll be able to post comments [once you've earned 50 reputation points](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).)

Comment: If you first split by `/*` and then by `*/`, you'll also include the content of the comment blocks, which the OP is trying to avoid ("Is there a way of removing all of the comment blocks…?" and "I'd also need to remove all of the lines inside of the comment blocks.").
It's unclear how the comment re joining relates to the question, given that the SQL commands should be processed one by one. (This is a revised form of an earlier comment)